# c# recognize sql uniqueidentifier

Tags: c#, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I have a method that I want to use differently based on the type of input. This is what I have:

```
public static DataTable GetS(string source = null, string customer = null)
    {
        if (source != null && customer == null) 
        {
            return GetDataTableFromQuery("db.GetS", new object[] { "@source", source });
        }
        else if (source == null && customer != null)
        {
            return GetDataTableFromQuery("db.GetS", new object[] { "@customer", customer });
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Bad input. Call GetS with GetS(source) or GetS(null,customer).");
        }
    }
```

The sp looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [db].[GetS]

    @source as nvarchar(128) = NULL,
    @customer as nvarchar(128) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
IF @customer IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        db.S
    WHERE
        [Source] = @source
END
IF @source IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        db.S
    WHERE 
        customer = @customer
END

END
```

This works fine for `GetS(source)` and `GetS(null,customer)` but I have 2 issues.

1. it goes bad if someone were to call with `GetS(customer)`
2. it doesn't look very pretty..

is there some way of doing something like this(pseudo-code):

```
public static DataTable GetS(string input)
{
    if(input is sql-uniqueidentifier)
    {
        return GetDataTableFromQuery("db.GetS", new object[] { "@source", input});
    }
    else
    {
        return GetDataTableFromQuery("db.GetS", new object[] { "@customer", input]);
    }
}
```

or is there a better way? (sure, I could make 2 separate methods, but I'd like to make it work with just one `Get`-method. Feels weird if I make a `GetSBySource` or something).

Comment: What is the exact problem? Developer errors? Why do you want to put this in a single method? Will there ever be a case that you want to pass in both values? What is the use of the `sql-identifier`?

Comment: I think it's more about architecture

Comment: If `source` is suppose to be a unque identifier then why is it a `string` and not a `Guid`?

Comment: Also personally I think you should separate that stored procedure up as well.

Comment: To see if a string contains a valid GUID you can use [`Guid.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse.aspx) for the return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, why not write two methode, this is not *weird!!*? I thing using two methods is the best way.

1. `public static DataTable GetSBySource(Guid source)`
2. `public static DataTable GetSByCustomer(string customer)`

This would make your API ways more usable and clear.

If you know, that one time you need it to pass an `Uniqueidentifier`, you could also make it generic:

```
public static DataTable GetS<T>(string input)
{
    if(T is Guid)
    {
        return GetDataTableFromQuery("db.GetS", new object[] { "@source", input});
    }
    else
    {
        return GetDataTableFromQuery("db.GetS", new object[] { "@customer", input]);
    }
}
```

But then you should also make your input generic, because passing `Guid`s as `string`s around, is not very nice...

Using bad method definitions, will cause a lot of problems, when changing the code. For example you need to pass a Guid to the method, which only accepts string, than refactoring or changing the code will be very hard. Futhermore the definition of a method, should describe it's usage...

Comment: ok. Thanks for reply, I actually went with the 2 separate methods in the end =)